# how to get google maps route by sending the two latitudes and longitudes

Tags: google-maps, webview, xcode6

Basically what I want is to use a webView to show google map but an URL wish I could send both the position of origin and destination so that when the page is loaded the route is displayed.

I have a list of positions of different branches and would like to do is to select a branch is displayed on the map the shortest route from the position where the device is located and the selected branch.

There is an option that is the Google Maps URL Scheme, but not how it works.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) to calculate the route. If you are showing the map using Google Maps JavaScript API you can use [Direction Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) that is included in the Map itself.

Comment: There is an option that is the Google Maps URL Scheme, but not how it works.https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that turned me perfect for what I needed and use a webView and link to google maps route with two positions as follows:
 https://www.google.cl/maps/?saddr=origin_latitude,origin_longitude&daddr=destination_latitude,destination_longitude&directionsmode=transit